# EJECUTAR LIBRERIA DE MATH.H DE C EN VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Tags: c, linux, vscode

Estoy intentando hacer una simple operación de raíz cuadrada en c en visual studio code, desde una maquina remota conectada a linux pero nose si estoy ejecutando bien, ya que el resultado de debería ser no se ejecuta al poner el comando `gcc hello.c` me sale el siguiente error
`` /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cca8oRJe.o: in function `main': hello.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `sqrt' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``
el codigo que puse esta aqui

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
   double a,resultado;
    a=4;
    resultado= (double) sqrt(a);
   printf ("el resultado es %lf",resultado);
   return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida a SO. Stephanie, coloca texto en vez de imágenes en las preguntas.. por lo menos en casos como estos donde es salida de consola.

Comment: Te falta el flag para indicar que quieres usar la libreria matematica. (`-lm`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi experiencia, es porque el linker (ok ok, enlazador) (`ld`) no puede encontrar dicho símbolo en las librerías que está tomando en cuanta para hacer el enlazado. Supongo que tienes que indicar la ruta al so donde está definida dicha función (o algo parecido).

Si, efectivamente eso es. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-math

Tienes que colocar `-lm` al hacer la llamada a gcc.

```
gcc hello.c -lm
```

Comment: muchas gracias si con eso salio, disculpen la inexperiencia :'v

Comment: Tranquila.... yo todavía me doy contra las paredes con estos problemas porque no trabajo en c/c++ con frecuencia.